# Magento boilerplate / blank / skeleton / naked themes for theme development

Tags: magento-1, theme

Does anyone out there know of a good, clean boilerplate / blank / skeleton / naked theme (unsure of the proper term myself) besides the `base/default`? Not that it is bad, but sometimes another one may be more suited to a particular theme-cut job. It would be the [Magento equivalent of this](http://speckyboy.com/2010/03/22/10-blanknaked-wordpress-themes-perfect-for-development/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few magento templates based on different HTML/CSS frameworks. But check the links. I'm no frontend developer and have therefore no idea, how good they are.

#### 960gs

http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/making-and-breaking-the-grid-with-960-grid-system/

#### bootstrap

http://bootstrapped.magenthon.com/
https://github.com/cvaldemar/magento-bootstrap

#### yaml

http://forum.itratos.de/showthread.php?19136-YAML-f%C3%BCr-Magento

#### boilerplate

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-boilerplate/

Comment: Many links / projects are outdated. You may want to update your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend Magento Blank Theme - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blank-theme.html. While not the greatest, it is created & maintained by the Magento team.

Comment: It's not an enterprise edition ready-theme, though.

Comment: It comes with magento now

Comment: Or better, it's *not* maintained by Magento.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a magento boilerplate which includes custom templates, js files, less css and other goods!

check it out over on GitHub https://github.com/jasonalvis/magento-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice HTML5 Boilerplate template you can probably use, it's a bit outdated so perhaps you might want to implement replace it with the latest boilerplate version.

Magento files can be found here: https://github.com/zeljkoprsa/Magento-Boilerplate The boilerplate project can be found here: http://html5boilerplate.com/