# How to implement twitter bootstrap in magento theme step by step?

Tags: theme, design

I'm creating a new theme for magento with twitter bootstrap.Can some one help me to do this with bacis step by step procedure.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825717/is-it-possible-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-to-create-a-magento-site

Comment: There are even more bootstrap implementations, there is no need to do it on your own:

https://github.com/EcomDev/mbootstrap

http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/961/217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think I have just the right answer for you:

http://www.redlightblinking.com/magento-tutorials/day-1-creating-a-magento-reponsive-theme-with-twitter-bootstrap

It's a really good explanation step by step.

Comment: You should add some explanations in your answer instead of just a simple link. At least a 2 line summary.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for ways to do this from scratch yourself but I would suggest checking out Webcomms attempt. They have worked with Bootstrap for Magento for a while but with the BS 3 release, they made their work public.

http://www.webcomm.com.au/blog/2013/09/introducing-magento-boilerplate-a-twitter-bootstrap-3-powered-html5-mobile-first-starter-theme

I didn't have time to implement it myself yet but from a quick look there are things like fully implementing BS navigation left to do but other than that it looks solid.

Good luck!